# Cycle windows over all workspaces in XFCE (while being able to cycle over one workspace)

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, xfce

I am aware of the `xfwm4` -> `general` -> `cycle_workspaces` setting but I want to have two shortcuts:

1. cycles over the windows of the current workspace
2. cycles over the windows of all workspaces

Answer (score 6):

Great for [jeremija](https://askubuntu.com/a/175051/196255), but his code gives me an error. I found this easier:

```
if $(xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/cycle_workspaces)
then
  xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/cycle_workspaces -s false
else
  xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/cycle_workspaces -s true
fi
```

Comment: +1 because I have tested this working in Xubuntu 14.04. Make sure to include `#!/bin/bash` and save as file with `.sh` file extension. Then run `bash *.sh` in Terminal to test. If you have opened **Settings Manager** > **Window Manager Tweaks** running on the same workspace, user can see the option `Cycle through windows on all workspaces` is enabled/disabled after the running the script each time.

Comment: Xubuntu 18.04.3, still working.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize what is included in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> using `Settings > WM Tweaks > Cycling`.

Maybe in addition to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> you want to use a task-switcher such as `Skippy-XD`:

- [Is there a task switcher (alt-tab) for Linux (xfce) that allows to select application by a mouse click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170016/is-there-a-task-switcher-alt-tab-for-linux-xfce-that-allows-to-select-applic/396322#396322)

In `Xfce 4.10` you can easily bind `skippy-xd` command to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or similar) in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`.

Comment: @snoop: I've rejected all your edits over the last couple of days.  Not even reading them any more: it's too much work to actually let the (very few) good ones through and then re-edit the bad ones.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but may help.

Sve this code to a file (don't forget chmod +x) and map a hotkey to execute this script, for example Win+Tab. This script will toggle the /general/cycle_workspaces setting so that the next time you use Alt+Tab it will cycle only the current workspace or all workspaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD_VALUE=$(xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/cycle_workspaces)

if [ $OLD_VALUE == "true" ]; then
  echo 'will now disable workspace cycling'
  NEW_VALUE="false"
fi

if [ $OLD_VALUE == "false" ]; then
  echo 'will now turn on workspace cycling'
  NEW_VALUE="true"
fi

xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/cycle_workspaces -s $NEW_VALUE
```