# Is there a task switcher (Alt+Tab) for Xfce that allows to select application using a mouse click?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, task-management

I feel that the standard task switcher under Xfce isn't very good. For example it doesn't allow you to select an application by mouse clicking on it. On Windows for example, there is a program called `taskSwitchXP`, which greatly extends the standard functionality of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. In additional it allows you to select an application by a mouse click.

Is there a program with such functionality for Linux?

Comment: Any kind of panel allows you to select applications by mouse click. You can install one of them, make it very large, and set to auto-hide.

Comment: @user55822 yes, but if panel that appears when you hold alt-tab would allow you to activate an application by mouse click on it, i'll be much happier.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Something like 'Mac OS X exposé' / 'Compiz Scale' / 'KDE Present Windows' in Openbox / LXDE / Xfce?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/262433/something-like-mac-os-x-expose-compiz-scale-kde-present-windows-in-ope).

Comment: This feature comes by default in Xubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Skippy-XD`](https://github.com/richardgv/skippy-xd) for this. It is a full-screen task-switcher for X11 similar to Mac OS X's Exposé feature, and works nicely with `Xfce`. To install latest development packages (recommended), use the [Skippy-XD PPA (daily)](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd-daily). In `Xfce 4.10` you can easily bind `skippy-xd` command to `Alt + Tab` in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`.

Comment: This may be useful if used with a different shortkey than Alt-Tab, as it doesn't extend the functionality of the normal Alt-Tab action, it reduces it:  it only presents the windows but cannot cycle with Alt-Tab (you need to use the arrows) or select them with release (you have to use Enter).

Comment: there's a fork for those in 2019 that want to use skippy-xd:
https://github.com/dreamcat4/skippy-xd

Answer (score 0):

For those who are on Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 you can upgrade to [Xfce 4.12](http://www.xfce.org/about/tour) which comes with additional list and preview modes for Alt+Tab Window/Task switcher and many more improvements using this [tutorial](http://ubuntuportal.com/2015/03/how-to-upgrade-xfce-4-10-to-xfce-4-12-in-xubuntu-14-04-and-xubuntu-14-10.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/extras
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot now
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20, you can activate the configuration *Window Manager Tweaks* → *Compositor* → *Show windows preview in place of icons when cycling*.

[image: Window Manager Tweaks]