# Something like 'KDE Present Windows' / 'Compiz Scale' / 'Mac OS X exposé' in Openbox / LXDE / Xfce?

Tags: lubuntu, xfce, lxde, openbox

Is there a DE-independent utility to show all windows beside each other in more lightweight DEs like Openbox, LXDE or Xfce?

Something like this: 
[image]

Comment: You want the spread, like [this](http://www.abload.de/img/overview_gnome-shell91kde.jpeg)?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get this Mac OS X exposé behavior?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138334/how-do-i-get-this-mac-os-x-expose-behavior)

Comment: While they have one answer in common that question is about compiz and this one is about openbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [Skippy-XD](http://code.google.com/p/skippy-xd/)? It is a full-screen task-switcher for X11 similar to Mac OS X's `Exposé` feature.

From the above site:

> Skippy-XD is a standalone application for providing a window picker with live previews (including live video) on Linux desktops that run an X server with compositing support. That means it's not baked into the window manager, and the compositing is not being used all the time. So the performance of you're window manager isn't degraded, but you still get a window picker that's every bit as pretty as OSX's Exposé or KWin's "Present Windows", with all the desktop-navigational efficiency. Compositing only takes effect when you press the hotkey to display the window picker.

I've tried it and it works well, though it doesn't include window decorations.

[image]

To install latest development packages (recommended), use the [Skippy-XD PPA (daily)](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd-daily). If you use `Xfce`, you can easily bind `skippy-xd` command to <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt + Esc</kbd> in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`. For other DEs it should work similarly.

---

**Binding Skippy-XD to a screen corner**

You can use `xdotool` to bind skippy-xd to a screen corner. First, make sure `xdotool` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Add the following line to your autostart applications:

```
xdotool behave_screen_edge bottom-right exec skippy-xd
```

Valid location keys are:

```
left
top-left
top
top-right
right
bottom-left
bottom
bottom-right
```

xdotool is very lightweight and should have next to no negative impact on your system.

Source for the screen corner binding technique:

http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/expose-type-behaviour-in-openbox/#comment-13674

Comment: I now live years without window decorations =)

Comment: I think it's worth adding the instruction for binding it to the corner: http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/05/23/expose-type-behaviour-in-openbox/

Comment: I cannot make it switch windows with Alt-Tab - that only presents them. To switch I have to use the arrows and then Enter in order to select

Comment: the above was the deb version. testing the daily ppa version, it was simply impossible to leave the program without closing all windows: buggy and old