# Xubuntu XFCE switcher icons

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, application-switcher

Is it possible to somehow modify the XFCE <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> switcher?

What I'd like:

1. use theme icons (for some apps it uses some lowres-non-theme ones, for others it works nice)
2. don't make tiny previews for gimp, ristretto, etc.

I'm at 13.04 Xubuntu.

Some apps, that have "ugly" icons in switcher: Terminator, Clementine, Skype, Synaptic
Some apps, that have the nice theme's icons: Chromium, Firefox, Thunderbird

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straightforward way to deal with low-resolution icons, other than manually tweaking the icon theme and replacing the offending icons. And I don't think that you can get rid of the previews.

But instead of modifying the default `xfwm4` task-switcher, you could easily replace it with a different task-switcher like [Skippy-XD](http://code.google.com/p/skippy-xd/). So instead of being presented with icons, you would have actual previews of your windows.

See [Something like 'KDE Present Windows' / 'Compiz Scale' / 'Mac OS X exposé' in Openbox / LXDE / Xfce?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262433/something-like-mac-os-x-expose-compiz-scale-kde-present-windows-in-ope) for some usage and installation details (and screenshots). But in short you can install latest development packages from [Skippy-XD PPA (daily)](https://launchpad.net/~landronimirc/+archive/skippy-xd-daily). Then you can bind `skippy-xd` command to <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt + Esc</kbd> or whatever.